# Help with algorithm for organaizing blocks

Tags: algorithms

So I'm stuck on this problem for around a week, tried different approaches and having a hard time coming up with a solution.

What I'm trying to achieve is to **fit blocks horizontally inside another block**.

Overlapping blocks would be "pushed" horizontally, blocks should resize to fit the container block.

Please see images, hope it makes more sense.

[image]

Can anyone point me to the right direction here?

I'm trying to come up with a solution for displaying a time schedule.
The black outline can be considered as a "day" and the red boxes are the "events" in that day. Each event has a *start* and an *end* time, hence the different lengths.

The two images are two examples of how the events should be organaized with two different sets of input.

Overlapping events means that their start and end times hits other events duration.

The goal is to stack the events from left to right in case of overlapping while resize and position them accordingly.

Comment: more explanation needed

Comment: What is the relationship between the two images? What do you mean by "overlapping"? What does it mean to "push" a block?

Comment: How does the box on the left relate to the one on the right?  I think browsers do this kind of thing, as they flow various content to fit in arbitrarily sized windows.  You might search on how browsers flow UI.

Comment: Lets considerar a simplified example where you only have two events and each event has 60% duration of a day. If you have two events overlapping, you probably should not shrink them, you apparently want to move the overlapping event that start after to the finish time of the first event. But in that case either your "outer block" must go wider (meaning it does not represent a day anymore) or the moved event can eventually go out of the outer box. If that is not allowed then you need to shrink one event or the other or both. There is a need for additional rules to make the solution unique.

Comment: Also take a look on PERT/CPM schedullng.

Comment: The first step is to find clusters of overlapping blocks. This can be done with single-linkage clustering, disjoint sets, or simpler algorithms (for each unprocessed item, check overlap with each already-processed item. If an overlap is found, group all the overlapping items together into a cluster) and then, within each cluster, sort each item by its starting time.

Comment: How would you determine the position of each block? Since blocks in different clusters may potentially have different width (based on the number of items in the cluster), it's not just a matter of multiplying by their position in the cluster. They somehow should be aware of other clusters in the containing block.

Comment: What is the time axis - left to right or top to bottom? What does the other axis represent? IMHO this question is still too unclear for a sensible answer.

Comment: top-bottom: time axis. left-right: nothing, just a visual separation.

Comment: *[wonders if this isn't just a variation on the bin packing or stock cutting problems]*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is roughly how I managed to solve it.

First I minimized number of columns by finding maximal number of not intersected events on each step, then I grouped them together, and after that resize the rest of events to fit free space.